# I'm receiving the wrong array values for this loop

Tags: java, arrays

For a homework problem I was asked to write a program that keeps track of the sales for different types of salsa. Printing out the Types of salsa and their amount sold, total, most and least sold salsa. I seem to have everything working except for some reason in my loop where I'm printing out values for the amount sold it only shows the first value.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HW0604 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many types of salsa were sold: ");
        int x = input.nextInt();
        String salsa[] = salsa(x);
        int jars[] = (jars(salsa));
        int most = most(jars);
        int least = least(jars);
        int total = total(jars);
        print(salsa,jars,most,least,total);
    }
    public static String[] salsa(int x){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String y[] = new String[x];
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
            int j=i+1;
        System.out.print("What is the name of Salsa number " + j +" : ");
        String salsa = input.nextLine();
            y[i]= salsa;
        }
        return y;
    }
    public static int[] jars(String x[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int y[] = new int[x.length];
        for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
            System.out.print("How many jars of " + x[i] + " salsa were sold: "); 
            y[i] = input.nextInt();     
            }
        return y;
    }
    public static int total(int x[]){
        int y = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
            y = y + x[i];
        }
        return y;
    }
    public static int most(int x[]){
        int y = 0;
        int z = x[0];
        int j = 0;
        for(int i = 1;i<x.length;i++){
            if(x[i]>z){
                x[i]=z;
                y = j;
                j++;
            }   
        }
        return y;   
    }
    public static int least(int x[]){
        int y = 0;
        int z = x[0];
        int j = 0;
        for(int i = 1;i<x.length;i++){
            if(x[i]<z){
                x[i]=z;
                y = j;
                j++;
            }   
        }
        return y;   
    }
    public static void print(String salsa[],int jars[],int most,int least, int total){
        System.out.println("Salsa Sales Report");
        System.out.println();
        for(int i = 0; i<salsa.length;i++){
            System.out.println(salsa[i] + " sold: " + jars[i]);     
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Total Jars sold: " + total);
        System.out.println("Most jars sold: " + salsa[most]);
        System.out.println("Least jars sold: " + salsa[least]);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me determine what is wrong? I used the same method to input integers into an array and to print them before and it never had this problem is there anything conflicting with the jars[] array?

Comment: Have they taught you the concept of Object Oriented Programming (OOP) yet? It might be easier if you had a `Salsa` object that you can set the `sold`, `name`, `jars`, etc properties to instead of creating multiple arrays.

Comment: @Ceelos Not yet, we were just introduced to arrays. Though I believe the problem lies in then jars method since the total method only sums up the first value of the jars array.

Comment: This is not an MCVE.

Answer (score 5):

In `most()` and `least()` methods, you are modifying the contents of array passed in the argument and hence, it overwrites the original values. Below are the changes needed:

in `most()` method, change `x[i]=z;` to `z=x[i];`

and, in `least()` method, change `x[i]=z;` to `z=x[i];`

`x[i]=z` actually replaces all the values with minimum value in supplied array (`jars` in our case) and that's why, print method shows same values.

Answer (score 1):

In the methods `most` and `least` you need to do `z=x[i];` instead of `x[i]=z;`

Instead of finding the least and most, you are actually replacing the values in the original array by doing `x[i]=z`.